# Bootstrap 3 grid project

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay so I have to make a webpage that looks like the photo. The above site is not really interesting right now, but it's about the tiles that needs to look like the picture. But I don't know how to do it and could use some help. I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 and have to use that.

You see that it doesn't look perfect and when I make the screen smaller it is completely messed up. What I am asking is some help on how I should do this.

This image shows how it is supposed to look like.
[image: Image of how it should look]

This image shows how it looks like right now.
[image: Image of how it looks right now]

My code in a snippet.

```css
.background {
    background-color: #24a5e8;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.text {
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-left: 4%;
}
#h2 {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
#hr {
    border-color: white;
    margin-left: 2em;
    width: 17em;
}
#span{
    margin-left: 3em;
}

.tegels {
    font-family: Tw Cen MT;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="bootstrap-iso">

<div class="container-fluid"> <!-- container-fluid -->
    <div class="row"> <!-- row1 -->
        <div class="background"> <!-- background -->
            <div class="row"> <!-- row2 -->
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-8 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h2 id="h2">ONZE SERVICE</h2>
                        <hr id="hr">
                        <span>Voor klein en middenbedrijf zijn wij het aangewezen</span> <br>
                        <span id="span">netwerk om online te ondernemen</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- row2 -->
        </div> <!-- /background -->
    </div> <!-- /row1 -->
</div> <!-- /container-fluid -->

<!--Alle tegeltjes-->
<div class="container"> <!-- container -->       
<div class="tegels"> <!-- tegels -->

<div class="row"> <!-- row -->
    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/92x91"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 2em; background-color: #e3e9f2;">
        <p style="font-size:20px;"><b> PRODUCTEN</b></p>
        <p style="font-size:15px;">Uw producten en diensten direct online delen in ons netwerk.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/92x21"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #e3e9f2;">
        <p style="font-size:20px;"><b>AANBIEDINGEN</b></p>
        <p style="font-size:15px;">Al uw aanbiedingen in een duidelijk overzicht.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-1">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/92x21"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #e3e9f2;">
        <div id="lokaal">
            <p style="font-size:20px;"><b>LOKAAL</b></p>
            <p style="font-size:15px;">Regionale kracht, naamsbekendheid en betere vindbaarheid.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div> <!-- /row -->
<div class="row"> <!-- row -->

    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
       <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/92x21"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-3" style="background-color: #e3e9f2;">
        <div id="aanbod">
            <p style="font-size:20px;"><b> AANBOD OP MAAT</b></p>
            <p style="font-size:15px;">Welke klant past er bij u? Hulp bij het sturen in de vraag en aanbod.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/92x21"></a>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-3" style="background-color: #e3e9f2;">
        <div id="netwerken">
            <p style="font-size:20px;"><b> NETWERKEN</b></p>
            <p style="font-size:15px;">Socialmedia netwerken koppelen aan uw account. Delen en volgen gaat bijna vanzelf.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/92x21"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-3" style="background-color: #e3e9f2;">
        <div id="tools">
            <p style="font-size:20px;"><b> TOOLS</b></p>
            <p style="font-size:15px;">Gebruiksgemak, eenvoudig, overzichtelijke software. Responsive HTML5. Kwaliteitsnorms.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /row -->
</div> <!-- /tegels -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
</div> <!-- /bootstrap -->
```

Comment: Update the snippet to include bootstrap...

Comment: add padding to your divs.

Comment: We can't do anything without more information or a complete example of your work

Comment: How should I add padding to my divs?

Comment: I can't add all the extra css files of bootstrap tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to put image and text into one col and not the separate ones this will mess up I mean : 
*Change this*

```
 <div class="col-md-1">
         <img src="img/overimages/Netwerk.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-3" style="background-color: #e3e9f2;">
    ...
    </div>
```

*With something like this*

```
<div class ="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
         **IMG here**
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
         **Text here..**
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use **xs** inside the that div's because they should be the same proportions for all the devices.

Comment: I did that it looks better, but between the image and the text there is too much space. They need to be beside each other

Comment: Or use the Media object and style it. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#media

Answer (score 0):

```css
.background {
  background-color: #24A5E8 !important;
  color: #fff;
}

.hr {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
}

.background .text h1,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

.background .text p {
  padding: 1%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.tegels {
  font-family: Tw Cen MT;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 1%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="background">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="text">
            <h1>ONZE SERVICE</h1>
            <hr class="hr">
            <p>Voor klein en middenbedrijf zijn wij het aangewezen<br> netwerk om online te ondernemen</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="tegels">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
          <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/81x81"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 2em; background-color: #e3e9f2;">
          <p style="font-size:20px;"><b> PRODUCTEN</b></p>
          <p style="font-size:15px;">Uw producten en diensten direct online delen in ons netwerk.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
          <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/81x81"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #e3e9f2;">
          <p style="font-size:20px;"><b>AANBIEDINGEN</b></p>
          <p style="font-size:15px;">Al uw aanbiedingen in een duidelijk overzicht.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
          <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/81x81"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #e3e9f2;">
          <div id="lokaal">
            <p style="font-size:20px;"><b>LOKAAL</b></p>
            <p style="font-size:15px;">Regionale kracht, naamsbekendheid en betere vindbaarheid.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
          <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/81x81"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #e3e9f2;">
          <div id="aanbod">
            <p style="font-size:20px;"><b> AANBOD OP MAAT</b></p>
            <p style="font-size:15px;">Welke klant past er bij u? Hulp bij het sturen in de vraag en aanbod.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
          <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/81x81"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #e3e9f2;">
          <p style="font-size:20px;"><b> NETWERKEN</b></p>
          <p style="font-size:15px;">Socialmedia netwerken koppelen aan uw account. Delen en volgen gaat bijna vanzelf.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
          <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/81x81"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-9 col-sm-4" style="background-color: #e3e9f2;">
          <div id="tools">
            <p style="font-size:20px;"><b> TOOLS</b></p>
            <p style="font-size:15px;">Gebruiksgemak, eenvoudig, overzichtelijke software. Responsive HTML5. Kwaliteitsnorms.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Above is the code showing desired result if viewed in full-screen mode**

Suggestions

1.Stick to the basics.

2.Use good code editors like atom, visual studio code etc.

3.Clear about the layout and code accordingly.

4.Learn about using developer tools. you can style your webpage and can do more stuff using it.

-Best luck